# Photo album with a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Could you please explain me why the 2nd, 3rd and 4th images in this jsfiddle get smaller and smaller in size?

http://jsfiddle.net/FdhL6/

Here is the HTML from the JSFiddle.

```
<div id="album">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Caption 1</td>
        <td>Caption 2</td>
        <td>Caption 3</td>
        <td>Caption 4</td>
        <td>Caption 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS.

```
#album {
    overflow: auto;
}

#album td {
    width: 40%;
}

#album img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I am trying to make a photo album with a horizontal scrollbar in the #album div. I want each image to be 40% of the width of the page. Now, with this width, only two and a half image would fit in the page. I want a scrollbar to appear for the remaining pictures in the #album div. The #album div should not exceed the width of the page.

Comment: Five table cells at 40% width each = 200%. What is your goal with that?

Comment: fibonacci!! just change width 40% to 20%

Comment: @j08691 I want each image to be 40% of the width of the page. Now, with this width, only two and a half image would fit in the page. I want a scrollbar to appear for the remaining pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tables for this. They present their own problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/FdhL6/2/

HTML

```
<div id="album">
    <ul class="stage">
        <li class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/>
            <span>Caption 1</span>        
        <li class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/>
            <span>Caption 2</span>        
        <li class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/>
            <span>Caption 3</span>        
        <li class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/>
            <span>Caption 4</span>        
        <li class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dj7aqdo.jpg"/>
            <span>Caption 5</span>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#album {
    overflow: auto;
}

ul.stage {
    padding-left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200%;
}

li.image-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
span {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

AS j08691 said, you are using 200% width of 100%, that is what is causing your results to be so wonky. You should only be allocating 100% of your width otherwise your overflow your container, jsFiddle might be compensating for this and causing the images to get smaller.